# Regex to capture a pattern when not preceded by a specific case

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have this test data:

1. Part succn by #400 - Azerjahan Husbai
2. Shares to #343 - Executors of the estate of #18 - Homaho Jurei
3. Shares as administrator of estate of #187 - Shone Jumaja to #448 - Socsa Husmai
4. Shares as administrator of estate of #187 - Shone Jumaja to #445 - Horo Te Fuka

I have this regex expression

```
^.*#(?<legacyId>\d*).*$
```

The capturing group here always captures the last occurrence of #\d*
So the current result set of the captured group with my current regex is

1. 400
2. **18**
3. 448
4. 445

i want to modify the regex so that result set becomes:

1. 400
2. **343**
3. 448
4. 445

The rule shouldn't be just to capture the first occurrence instead of last
what I want is to capture the group which **is not** preceded with "estate of "

I suspect I have to use combination of positive and negative lookahead?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which programming language or regex library you're using. That is critical information. Without it, I can only guess at what features are available to you.

The only significant clue you gave was the use of named capture. Since you used the `(?<name>)` syntax rather than `(?P<name>)`, that narrows down your regex flavor to probably one of the following:

- .NET
- Perl 5.10+
- PCRE 7+
- Java 7+
- Oniguruma 1.8.4+
- Ruby 1.9+ (which uses Oniguruma by default)
- Boost.Regex (not sure which version started supporting this)
- JavaScript with [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com) 0.5+
- JGsoft products like RegexBuddy

OK, so even that clue didn't narrow it down enough. The relevant feature to make your regex support your new rule might be negative lookbehind, but not all of the above support lookbehind at all, and almost all of them support different subsets of features *within* lookbehind.

Here's a solution that uses fixed-length negative lookbehind, to try to support a broad range of the above flavors in a simple way:

```
^.*#(?<!estate of #)(?<legacyId>\d+)
```

With this, you need to enable the flag that makes `^` and `$` match at line breaks. You must not enable the flag that allows dot to match line breaks, nor the flag for free-spacing and line comments. (These flags use different names and letters in different places.) I've placed the negative lookbehind after the `#` symbol for minor efficiency reasons.

Please do not make people guess what programming language and regex flavor you are using.